# How to get the xml sent by post in a REST API

Tags: go, go-echo

I want to build a rest app in which I have to get the values ​​that are sent by post as xml. How is the data recovered?

I'm using echo framework.

Comment: What have you found in your research? What have you tried? What issues did you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the Binding functionality of Echo, in combination with struct tags to provide the names you expect the XML keys to be.

```golang
type DoThingRequest struct {
    Name string `xml:"name"`
}
e.POST("/do_thing", func(c echo.Context) (err error) {
  body := new(DoThingRequest)
  if err := c.Bind(body); err != nil {
    return
  }
  
  // Do some stuff...
}
```

See https://echo.labstack.com/guide/binding/ for more information and options for binding.